# Sphero programing with nodeJS. How to sphero is keeping going?

Tags: ruby, node.js, sphero-api, sphero

i'm japanese student.so, I'm not good at in English.

I use "cylon-sphero". (https://github.com/hybridgroup/cylon-sphero)

But,not work keep going.
What would be the best thing to do?

e.g) I use under command. Sphero is go small and small.I want to keep 3seconds!!!!!

```
every((1), second(), function(){
 my.sphero.roll(60, 90);
}
```

by the way, version ruby-sphero-gem(https://github.com/hybridgroup/sphero).

I can use keep going. but I want to use nodeJS.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess... this problem was solved for speed more and more.

```
every((1), second(), function(){
 my.sphero.roll(150, 90);
}
```

> roll(speed, degree)
>   this speed ↑↑

sorry. this topic is okay.